# Pyramid: Routing schemas and restraints

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyramid

I have done my research and did some pattern matching trials but I still can not figure out how to:

1. Make part of the route optional. e.g.:

   /required **(/optional/{str})**
   Here the part in parentheses is optional.
2. Apply restraints to routing so instead of a wildcard string, it has to match an item from a tuple.

   /view_1/ **{('opt_a', 'opt_b', 'opt_c' ...)}**
   in this case, if an item from the tuple is matched, it routes if not 404 or FORBIDDEN

How can I achieve these?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pyramid does not support optional patterns in a route. The other answer suggests `*optional` but this will match much more than what you asked for which was one optional placeholder, and leaves you with no options at the end of the route for more patterns.

```
config.add_route('name_with_optional', '/required/{optional}/{str}')
config.add_route('name', '/required/{str}')
```

Now you want to use the same view for both I imagine, since you are thinking of the placeholder as optional. Thus, simply register the view for both cases:

```
@view_config(route_name='name_with_optional')
@view_config(route_name='name')
def my_view(request):
    optional = request.matchdict.get('optional')
```

The `optional` variable will be `None` if `'name'` was the matched route pattern.

As for your second question, you can simply create a custom predicate. This could be either on the route or the view (remember that these are separate in Pyramid). The signature for the predicate is different in each case.

A predicate on the route (less common):

```
def opt_must_contain(info, request):
    opt = info['match'].get('opt')
    return opt in ('opt_a', 'opt_b', 'opt_c')

config.add_route('my_route', '/view_1/{opt}', custom_predicates=[opt_must_contain])
```

If this predicate returns `False` then another route with the same pattern could be matched (the route is ignored).

A predicate on the view (more common):

```
def opt_must_contain(context, request):
    opt = request.matchdict.get('opt')
    return opt in ('opt_a', 'opt_b', 'opt_c')

config.add_route('my_route', '/view_1/{opt}')

@view_config(route_name='my_route', custom_predicates=[opt_must_contain])
def my_view(request):
    opt = request.matchdict.get('opt')
```

In the view we'll know `opt` is one of the required options.

Comment: Thanks for great answer! But it contains a little typo: info['matchdict'] should be info['match'].

Comment: fixed, told you that route predicates were less common!

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

It's tricky to explain, but what you want is here http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/narr/hybrid.html - it's not the easiest of reads, but explains what you're after.

**Update after further research**

Using:

```
config.add_route('name', 'foo/*optional')
```

it's possible to receive the remaining path elements as a tuple

Custom predicates can be used to filter url dispatch as described in  http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/urldispatch.html?awesome

Comment: Hello Jon. I've already read this. I think I will need to go with the Traverse or Hybrid route as you've also suggested. It's such a shame that the routing system does not cover the "optional" and tuple matching. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Phil - Thinking about it, the optional could work using add.route('whatever', '/required/*optional') where optional is simple and not /a/b/c/d etc...

Comment: **and** - I need to update Pyramid - read http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/urldispatch.html?awesome - and scroll down to Custom Route Predicates - that covers your tuple issue :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using custom route predicates, you can achieve both things using URL traversal. I wrote a [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11147511/320021) in response to your other question.

I believe traversal is a cleaner and "more natural" solution for such use cases.